# The function $f(x)=|x|^p,$ $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is strictly convex for $p>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $p>1$. In the paper [1] below, it says that The function $f(x)=|x|^p,$ $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is strictly convex.

I would like to prove that. By definition, We need to show that the Hessian matrix

$H=\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}\right)$ is positive definite (i.e, $x^{T}Hx>0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\{0\}.$) But this looks really tedious. So I am trying to verify the alternative equivalent definition:
$$|(1-t)w_{1}+tw_{2}|^{p}<(1-t)|w_{1}|^p+t|w_{2}|^{p}$$ for all $t\in]0,1[$ and $w_{1}\neq w_{2}$. Not much of trying because I don't know where to begin.

[1] P. Lindqvist, On the equation $div(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)+\lambda |u|^{p-2}u=0$, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 109, (1990), 157 - 164.

Comment: Can you clarify what the notation $|x|$ means for a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$? Is it the 2-norm?

Comment: The Euclidean norm $|x|:=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real variable function $\phi(t)=|t|^p$ is strictly convex in $\mathbb{R}$ and strictly increasing in $[0,\infty)$. The norm function $\mathbf{x}\mapsto \|\mathbf{x}\|_r$, $\|\mathbf{x}\|_r=\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}|x_j|^r\Big)^{1/r}$ is  convex

$\|(1-\alpha)\mathbf{a}+\alpha\mathbf{b}\|_r\leq (1-\alpha)\|\mathbf{a}\|_r + \alpha\|\mathbf{b}\|_r$. Applying $\phi$ leads to
$$
\|(1-\alpha)\mathbf{a}+\alpha\mathbf{b}\|^p_r\leq \Big((1-\alpha)\|\mathbf{a}\|_r + \alpha\|\mathbf{b}\|_r\Big)^p\leq (1-\alpha)\|\mathbf{a}\|^p_r+\alpha\|\mathbf{b}\|^p_r$$
with equality only if $\|\mathbf{a}\|_r=\|\mathbf{b}\|_r$.

Comment: The OP speaks of the 2-norm and not the p-norm

Comment: @marwalix: he states $p>1$ at the beginning of the question and does not specify $p=2$, In any case, the proof goes through for any $p>1$.

Comment: @Jean Leider.  In your notation $\|x\|_{p}=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^{p}_i|)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. But I am asking about $f(x)=|x|^{p}=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^{2}_i|)^{\frac{p}{2}}$. Can you modify your answer accordingly ?

Comment: @Medo: Just edited. One can use $\|x\|^p_r$ for $r,p>1$

Comment: @Jean Leider. Okay. You are using the convexity of the 2-norm  followed by the triangly inequality of the norm, and finally the strict convexity of $\phi(t)=t^p$ on $[0,\infty[$. The last  inequality in your answer should be strict.

Comment: $(1-\alpha)\|\mathbf{b}\|^p_r$ should read as $\alpha\|\mathbf{b}\|^p_r$.